# Рендеринг текста DirectWrite c Direct2d C++

Tags: c++, directx

[image: надо]

[image: есть сейчас]

Какой параметр нужно установить, чтобы рендеринг текста был как на рисунке 1?

Использую `DirectWrite` 
Вывожу текст методом `DrawText`.

Фабрика:

```
DWriteCreateFactory(<br/>
    DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,<br/>
    __uuidof(writeFactory),<br/>
    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown **>(&writeFactory)
);
```

Формат текста:

```
writeFactory->CreateTextFormat(
    msc_fontName,
    NULL,
    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL
    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_EXPANDED,
    msc_fontSize,
    L"",
    &textFormat
);
```

Нужно чтобы весь текст выводился сплошным цветом, без измененных пикселей.

Возможно ли вообще такое с `DirectWrite`?

Answer (score 0):

```
hr = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
         reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&writeFactory));

hr = DWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(
        L"Script",
        NULL,
        DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_REGULAR,
        DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
        DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
        msc_fontSize,
        L"en-us",
        &textFormat
    );
```